# Регулярное выражение для выделение нужного символа

Tags: java

Как можно выделить 1 из tasks/task?id=1&  , найти id= и & , и выделить символ между ними

Comment: [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13592236/312041)

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по регулярке `id=(\d+)` и брать первую букву.